# What's the best algorithm to move big data between two databases?

Tags: mysql

Say i have db1 which is MySQL server in which table1 has 500M rows of data and i want to move them to db1 in terradata or similar SQL db, what is the best efficient algorithmic way to copy the data programmatically using python and also any optimised way to reconcile the data between two dbs after the data is copied ?

Comment: For large volumes it is typically better to use utilities provided by the vendor(s) possibly with a named pipe (or similar) in the middle. But if you must use Python, use cursor methods like fetchmany and executemany directly and don't do any additional conversions - e.g. do NOT use something like pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Dont have answer for algorithm, but if you try to copy table in old database to new database, you can try use kafka connect use old database as source and new database as sink, more [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect)
example for kafka connect [demo](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/tree/master/kafka-to-database)

Comment: Linked repo doesnt **read from** Mysql, or write to a **different** database, as asked. I think Debezium docs would be better